# Purpose of Buffers in this Circuit

Tags: buffer, bridge

The schematic below is an H-bridge , the high and low mosfets are internal to the two ICs on the right side, their datasheet is [here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/BTS7970B_Datasheet.pdf?folderId=db3a304412b407950112b408e8c90004&fileId=db3a304412b407950112b43949b36d61).
What is the purpose of the part on the left, which I googled to be a buffer IC, datasheet [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ahc244.pdf).
Is it for the sake of circuit protection? 
My understanding of using a buffer is limited, I have always assumed they where used in cases where something could not source enough current to drive something else, so you use a buffer with higher current sourcing capability. Is this correct and is this the case here?
[image: H_bridge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a buffer and used because the drive source current at hdr P3 is not known. This buffer has almost no load on its inputs but can source +/- 8 mA per pin, even though the package has a wattage limit, depending on if you get a SOIC package or a DIP package. Maximum total current is limited to 50 mA.

That is more than enough to drive the H-bridge drivers. Speed limit for U1 is about 20 MHZ though 50 MHZ is possible with just 15 pF loads. Plenty fast for PWM if you are using that.

Comment: I thought I saw \$I_\text{OH}=-8\:\text{mA}\$ and \$I_\text{OL}=8\:\text{mA}\$ when \$V_\text{CC}=5\:\text{V}\$. Where'd you see the "24" figure, exactly? By the way, that H-bridge input specs are way down the sheet at 4.4.6 and require only microamps. Nowhere near the drive compliance of the AHC244. But I agree that since we don't know what's at the header... it's a safe way to be. (Though those \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$ pull-downs on the inputs of the AHC244 are pretty heavy loads already, so perhaps I'm not sure what's gained.)

Comment: @jonk. My bad. I corrected my answer. I had the standard 74HCxx series in mind.